# How to fix a menu and allow it moving only horizontal with a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed menu, but i don't get it ,how to enable moving it with the div container

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$('.menu').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
```

I use this Jquery snippet, it allows me only to move the menu by resizing, but i can't move the menu with the div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>


<div class="page-wrap">


<div class="page-content"> 

<div class="menu">

</div>



<div class="avatar-container">
<div class="avatar-puls"></div>
<div class="avatar-frame">
<img class="avatar-img" draggable="false" src="images/avatar.png">
</div>

<div class="circle"></div>

</div>


<div class="posts">

<div class="up-line"></div>

<div class="post">
<div class="cycle">
<img class="cycle-img" draggable="false" src="images/maps/1.png">
</div>
</div>

<div class="cycle-middle">
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="outer-dot"></div>
<div class="inner-dot"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/reload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modalEffects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function(){
$('.menu').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should provide more info and example HTML. Also fixed elements are positioned fixed to the viewport not to other elements.

Comment: Okay, i create a responsive design, when i resize the window the content and the menu drifting away, but i want to make these div's relative to each other, that the menu is only in this area i want.

Comment: œDiego Farina Already done